# Using Mootools to inject a template into an existing table, but getting rownum is undefined at eval

Tags: javascript, php, mootools

I am **very new** to MooTools and somewhat new to JavaScript.

I am trying to get a new row to show up on a button click. I have copied the code that another programmer did and adapted it to suit my needs (as far as I understand and on the instructions of my boss), but it is not working.

The click event registers, but when I debugged the code yesterday in the browser, I got a message that rownum is undefined, but today I don't get that error (but it still isn't working).

```
<button id="add-new-row" style="text-align:center;margin-top:5px;width:85px;" class="boxbutton">Add New</button>

// This is what should be injected on button click
<script id="connectedjobtemplate" type="text/plain">
    <tr id="childjobrow<%= rownum %>" class="<%= cl %>" data-row-id="<%= rownum %>">
        <td>
            <input class="childjobid" type="hidden" id="childjobid<%= rownum %>" name="childjobid[<%= rownum %>][transcribername]" value="0" />
            <input data-row-id="<%= rownum %>" id="assignee[<%= rownum %>]" name="childjobid[<%= rownum %>][transcribername]" class="" style="width:140px;" list="transcribers" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="hidden" id="transcriberid[<%= rownum %>]" name="childjobid[<%= rownum %>][transcriberid]" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-row-id="<%= rownum %>" id="refNum[<%= rownum %>]" name="childjobid[<%= rownum %>][refNum]" value="<%= refNum %>" class="" style="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-row-id="<%= rownum %>" id="pages[<%= rownum %>]" name="childjobid[<%= rownum %>][pages]" value="<%= pages %>" class="" style="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-row-id="<%= rownum %>" id="orderDate[<%= rownum %>]" name="childjobid[<%= rownum %>][orderDate]" value="<%= orderDate %>" class="" style="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-row-id="<%= rownum %>" id="nysid[<%= rownum %>]" name="childjobid[<%= rownum %>][nysid]" value="<%= nysid %>" class="" style="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-row-id="<%= rownum %>" id="dinNum[<%= rownum %>]" name="childjobid[<%= rownum %>][dinNum]" value="<%= dinNum %>" class="" style="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-row-id="<%= rownum %>" id="warrantNum[<%= rownum %>]" name="childjobid[<%= rownum %>][warrantNum]" value="<%= warrantNum %>" class="" style="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/underscore-1.8.3-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// VARIABLES
var lastrow = 0;

// TEMPLATE
var rowtemplate = _.template(document.getElementById('connectedjobtemplate').innerHTML);

window.addEvent('load', function() {
    if ($('linkedJobsBody').getChildren().length == 0) {
        addChildJobRow();
    }
});

$(document.body).addEvent('click:relay(#add-new-row)', function (e, el) {
    try{
        e.preventDefault();
        addChildJobRow();
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        logevent({jobid: jid,event:'click#add-new-row',uri:window.location.href, eventdata: e});
    }
});

function addChildJobRow() { 
    try {
        lastrow++;
        cl = (lastrow % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even');
        Elements.from(rowtemplate({
            rownum: lastrow,
            cl: cl
        })).inject($('linkedJobsBody'));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        logevent({jobid: jid, event: 'add-new-row', uri: window.location.href, eventdata: e});
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when I click the Add New button. I have put in alerts to show that it is going to the right function, so I know it's getting there. I don't understand the error that rownum is undefined at eval because I checked the other programmer's code and it's identical in that respect. I don't want to start messing with the JavaScript file as I am very new to MooTools.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The only reference to `rownum` seems to be inside the template you're passing to underscore - that's not mootools. 

Various other variables such as 'refNum' also appear to be undefined, so it might help to give a more complete or more minimal example that actually works.

Comment: @unilynx, thank you for your response. I will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final code that works. It turns out I had to pass several variables in or it wouldn't work.

```
function addChildJobRow() {
                try {
                    lastrow++;
                    let cl = (lastrow % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even');
                    var refNum = '<?php echo $this->MJob->getNewJobRef(232); ?>';
                    Elements.from(connectedjobtemplate({
                        rownum: lastrow,
                        cl: cl,
                        ref: refNum,
                        nysid: '',
                        dinNum: '',
                        warrantNum: ''
                    })).inject($('newChildJobTable'));
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }
```